# Microchip Studio / STK500 Got 0xc0, expected 0x00

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, avr, atmel, atmelstudio

This project started as a typical hobbyist (me) learning how to replicate an Arduino Uno's basic functionality on a breadboard using an ATMEGA328P-PU. The basic intent of the circuit is to trigger 8 otherwise independent Halloween props using a single input, either cycling them continuously or upon command based on an input from a PIR sensor.

After validating the effectiveness of my design on a breadboard I had SMT PCBs professionally made which use ATMEGA328P-AUs (the SMT equivalent).The complete PCB schematic is provided below.

My PCB manufacturer informed me that they received an error when trying to upload my hex file using their STK500 connected to my on board ICSP header. Subsequently, they shipped my prototype PCBs with bare ATMEGA328P-AUs.

Upon receiving the PCBs I was able to use an Arduino Uno as ISP connected to my PCB's on board ICSP header to successfully load the Arduino bootloader, then successfully upload my Arduino program. I have repeated this process successfully multiple times and have subsequently been able to validate that the PCB logic behaves as intended in my application. My pin out on my PCBs ICSP header is identical to the ICSP header on an Arduino. It is 8 pins because I added TX and RX at the top.

I installed Microchip Studio and connected an STK500 via COM1. In Device Programming I selected device ATMEGA328P and Interface ISP. When I click "Read" I get the error depicted below. When I connect an Arduino Uno everything reads fine which leads me to believe that while my circuit contains the components  required for a breadboard Arduino it is missing something that the STK500 needs to recognize it as a device.

After searching these forums and Google for similar problems the only two solutions that I can find are to use the internal clock (presumably on the ATMEGA328P?) and to "Disable Debugwire and Close" in Microchip Studio. All of the Debug functionality in Microchip Studio is greyed out for me and it isn't clear to me how I can change clock settings on a device that I can't communicate with. I did specifically incorporate an external clock to improve timing accuracy in my application, though, if that matters.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for responding old_timer! Shouldn't the STK500 be able to communicate with the chip regardless of what bootloader is (or even isn't) installed? The ICSP header on the Arduino has MISO and MOSI pins, it does not have RX / TX pins. That would lead me to conclude that only MISO / MOSI pins are in use since the STK500 can communicate with it successfully.

Comment: sorry you said that, the tx/rx are yours.   it should work yes.  have you tried non-arduino, non-arduino compatible, avr boards?

Comment: when you probed the reset line that is working near the chip and the miso/mosi are pulled up and working as well?

Comment: This is my first AVR project so I don't have any other boards to try. The only other chips that I have to work with are ATMEGA328P-PUs that I bought at the breadboard stage of this project. I was able to install one of those chips that had never been programmed directly in to the STK500 and it did read successfully.